Excel Macro ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create ignores SourceData
Just before today, it worked pretty well.
I have created macro, that creates pivot table, but it creates from active worksheet.
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "ESR for pivot!R1C1:R1048576C22", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=6



Just after creating sourcedata it looks like it's ignoring when correct worksheet just has different columns.

Tried recording macro manually. When recording it works fine, creates same code but if replay that, same error.

You really shouldn't use entire columns, but you need single quotes round the sheet name as it contains spaces.
